How to pass parameter from Lightning flow to Lightning Email Template to LWC
I have a requirement to display a list of records in email. Records are constructed from 3 objects. Since it's not possible to use a list in the Lightning template I decided to use LWC in the Lightning template. However, there is an issue with how to pass parameters from Flow to Lightning template and template to LWC.
For this, I have created an LWC component(targets="lightningStatic__Email") and one input variable 'recordid' defined in metaxml file to get 'recordId' from the email template.  The input field of LWC is coming on Lightning Template and in the email action of flow. images of the email template and flow are below. I am not sure how to pass the parameter till LWC. Without a parameter, LWC won't be able to get records from the apex controller. Any help will be appreciated.
Flow Image

Email Template Builder image

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>61.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightningStatic__Email</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningStatic__Email">
            <property label="Record Id" name="recordId" type="String"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>

JS file
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class EmailTemplateTest extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
}

HTML
<template>
    <div class="slds-card__body">
        <p>{recordId}</p>
    </div>
</template>


I found one link. Currently, LWC for email is not supported Apex classes except PicklIstEntry and DynamicPicklist class
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-config-for-email-builder-custom-components-tips.html
